# How to use IF statements, that if met proceed to a part in the powershell script

Tags: powershell, if-statement, statements

I have written a Powershell script that installs a bunch of features and roles in Server 2012 and the script works perfectly, but I need help figuring out how to check if UAC is enabled, if it is, to prompt that the server will restart when they press enter or if it is not, then to proceed to the next line, or the next functioning line where the script really starts.

So I have this line that checks to see if UAC is enabled or diabled

```
 (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA
```

If UAC is disabled, it prints a 0 and if UAC is enabled it prints a 1.

If it is disabled, I would like it to continue to a line in the script that reads

```
Start-Transcript
```

If it is enabled, it reads 1 and I would like it to proceed to this line

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force
Restart-Computer
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Why would you want to disable UAC?

Comment: I want this to be an unattended script, with UAC enabled there is a manual step, this will be used on many machines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA -eq 0 )
{
    Start-Transcript
}
else
{
    New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force
    Restart-Computer
}
```

Comment: Running this method, it seems to reboot every time with this message

     New-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed.
At C:\ContactCanvas_6520\1PRE.-FINAL-1-11-2017.ps1:26 char:5
+     New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\polici ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...policies\system:String) [New-ItemProperty], Securit 
   yException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand

Comment: Looks like you're using an account that doesn't have access to the registry or the registry isn't loaded as a PSDrive.

Comment: this is the account I have been working on this always from, trying to figure it our now, but i thought I would provide you with the message in case you saw something stick out.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe use that account and see if there is a PSDrive for HKLM. However, its a permissions error so its usually related to access the account had.

Comment: Meh, it was my fault, the portion where it reads EnableLUA, I wrote EnableUA and it doesnt exist, so it wasnt working.  Thank you so much it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement for this, so you can also handle a situation where the Registry lookup does not return one of the expected values:

```
$uacStatus = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\...).EnableLUA
switch ($uacStatus) {
  0 { Start-Transcript }
  1 { New-ItemProperty ...; Restart-Computer }
  default { Write-Host "UAC status not recognized: $uacStatus"; exit 1 }
}
```

Comment: Running this method, it seems to reboot every time with this message

   New-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed.
At C:\ContactCanvas_6520\1PRE.-FINAL-1-11-2017.ps1:26 char:5
+     New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\polici ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...policies\system:String) [New-ItemProperty], Securit 
   yException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, your solution worked as well, but i also had a typo i entered my, thank you it worked.